# how to enclose legend in box

Tags: r, plot, legend

How can I enclose the legend shown in the code below inside a box? I am trying the  "legend" function but of no avail.

```
library("affy")
library("affycoretools")
data(sample.ExpressionSet)
plotPCA(sample.ExpressionSet, groups =
       as.numeric(pData(sample.ExpressionSet)[,2]), groupnames =
       levels(pData(sample.ExpressionSet)[,2]))
```

Comment: When I try your code sample, the legend is enclosed in a box. By the way, you should add `library(affycoretools)` at the beginning of your sample code since `plotPCA` belong to that package.

Comment: @plannapus thanks, but I am not getting the enclosing box. I tried to run this again without any luck